# Easy imports for Java IDEs?

Tags: java, ide, libraries, import

In Eclipse, you can press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> key and it'll pull in all required imports and organize them.  It generally works well.

Is there anything like this for other common Java IDEs?  JCreator, NetBeans, etc?

Comment: Most of the features of eclipse are in NetBeans and IntelliJ. The main difference is how well it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for netbeans for auto import.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for IntelliJ Optimize Imports, I believe.